# Does the Bouncy Castle SCrypt implementation include the factors in the result?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, scrypt

I'm pretty sure it doesn't, but I want to confirm whether the SCrypt implementation in Bouncy Castle for Java, `SCrypt.generate()`, includes the parameters in the result (like an implementation for NodeJS does).

Comment: If you mean [`SCrypt.generate()`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/SCrypt.html#generate(byte[],%20byte[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) then no, it only returns generated key bytes.

Comment: Yes, that one._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Bouncy castle does not include them in result, but if you want similar result you can use SpringFramework SCrypt.

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.SCrypt;
public static void ScryptSpringFramework()
{   
    public static String plaintextPassword  = "myname123456";
    SCryptPasswordEncoder sEncoder = new SCryptPasswordEncoder();

    String str1 = sEncoder.encode(plaintextPassword);
    System.out.println("SpringFramework output of "+plaintextPassword+" = "+str1);              
}
```

[Here is the link for the SpringFramework crypto.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto/5.0.0.M3)